# Race condition between trap_exit EXIT msg and common msg

Tags: erlang

Hi the question is as following:
Assume we have processes A and B which are linked. Process's A flag trap_exit is set to true. Let B process send a msg to A and then exit:

```
PidA ! 'msg',
exit(reason).
```

What I wanna know if we can be shure that the process A will receive 'msg' and only after It {'EXIT', Pid, reason} will come ? Can we predict the ordering of msgs? I can't found any proofs in documentation, but I guess that it will work that way, but I need some proofs. Don't want to have race condition here..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As to not leave this question hanging. This is the discussion in erlang-questions mailing list:

http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.erlang.general/66788

Long story short: all messages are signals (or all signals are messages), exits are seen as messages from the process, guaranteed to arrive in the same order they were sent.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a code smell to me. Why do you need to rely on `trap_exit`? Have you thought of alternatives, e.g. proper monitoring?

Comment: I don't think that relying on trap_exit is unproper monitoring. As msgs ordering is predictable(it is mentioned in docs) I only wanna know dois it remains true for the situation above.

Comment: Well, you cannot trap the `kill` signal (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134078/can-i-trap-exitself-kill).

Comment: Are you using OTP behaviours?

Comment: I know about kill signal, and yes, I use OTP. I'm interested only about the question above. Any way thanks for trying to show me where I'm wrong.

Comment: Then you should reward @Mamut ;)

Comment: Yes you are right) He confirmed my guesses, which I posted as a reply to kjw0188. =) But still, I think that this should be mentioned briefly in the official documentation.

Comment: For these kinds of things, you should consider using `Mref = erlang:monitor(process, Pid)` as well. Usually monitors are safer to use for this and you don't have to trap exits to make those work. In OTP, the only real reason to set `trap_exit` is if you want to clean up something *guaranteed* even if the supervisor kills you. Avoiding having to do this is usually good style.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the O'Reilly Erlang programming book here, and in Chapter 4, in the section Message Passing, it says:

> Messages are stored in the mailbox in the order in which they are delivered.  If two messages are sent from one process to another, the messages are guaranteed to be received in the same order in which they are sent.  This guarantee is not extended to messages sent from different processes, however, and in this case the ordering is VM-dependent.

However, in your case, I'm not sure the exit message actually comes from process B.  It might originate somewhere in the bowels of the VM.  If I wanted to be sure, I would actually have process A trigger the exit of process B when it receives your notification message instead.

Comment: Yes, I have read the book and I remeber it, but nothing is said about the signals. Finally I found erlang draft on the official site http://www.erlang.org/download/erl_spec47.ps.gz (Paragraph 10.6) And according to the draft messages internally are signals. And as the ordering of the signals from single process is predictable we can also say it about my situation.